# How often do Virtual Machines migrate in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I just read an interesting [article](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.de/2015/03/Google-Compute-Engine-uses-Live-Migration-technology-to-service-infrastructure-without-application-downtime.html) about Google Transparent Maintenance and now I am thinking about how often a virtual machine migrates per day.

I didn't find any statistics so I am wondering if anybody can give me some information about this?

Another point that comes into my mind is doing live migration not only for maintenance purpose but for saving energy by migrating virtual machines and power off physical hosts. I found many papers discussing this topic so I think it's a big topic in currently research.

Does somebody know if there is any cloud provider already performing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

**How often do scheduled infrastructure maintenance events happen?**
Infrastructure maintenance events don't have a set interval between occurrences, but generally happen once every couple of months.
**How do I know if an instance will be undergoing a infrastructure maintenance event?**
Shortly before a maintenance event, Compute Engine changes a special attribute in a virtual machine's metadata server before any attempts to live migrate or terminate and restart the virtual machine as part of a pending infrastructure maintenance event. The `maintenance-event` attribute will be updated before and after an event, allowing you to detect when these events are imminent. You can use this information to help automate any scripts or commands you want to run before and/or after a maintenance event. For more information, see the Transparent maintenance notice documentation.

SOURCE: [Compute Engine Frequently Asked Questions.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq?hl=en#maintenance)

Comment: Please do not rely on the "couple of months" number for your system design, as there can be a variety of reasons that would require more frequent migrations. For example, let's assume there was a bug discovered in the host kernel. Google would want to migrate and upgrade asap, not waiting for the "couple of months" interval.